# Make intents that needs more than one arguments?

Tags: android, mosby

In mosby and in examples, the intent methods in the view takes one argument at most. How do I pass more than 1 arguments to interactor through a presenter?

Comment: put the code here, is hard to know what you talking about

Comment: Intents are dictionaries... You put as much as you can in them using unique keys

Comment: You need to use the intent.putExtra() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap your paramaeters into a class like this:

```
class MyParams {
  final int a;
  final String b;

  MyParams(int a, String b){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }
}
```

This is because in Rx `Observable<T>` takes exactly 1 Generic Type Argument.

Then your View has some intent like

```
interface MyView {
  Observable<MyParams> fooIntent();
}
```

There is also a class `android.support.v4.util.Pair` one could use if you have exactly 2 parameters.

Comment: Yeah it should be like this. So now im my case I have three modules namely data,domain and presentation. So should I make these params model in each layer with mapper classes?

Comment: I think it is not worthwhile to add this extra abstraction. It might seem very "clean" but if you just pass around pojos with strings, integers then it is completely fine to pass such a pojo around your layers. 
From my point of view it only makes sense if it contains some domain specific data that strongly belongs to one module so that the other modules should not know about it.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. Great library by the way